# from R console windows equivalent of wget

Tags: windows, r, wget

Hi I was wondering what the windows equivalent of wget is

I currently have a function in R that has the command

```
system("wget www.random.url.com/file")
```

to download a file from the internet from a mac/unix machine that is running R...what would the equivalent be for R in windows?

Comment: You could always install wget on your windows machine! Paul's answer is much better though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at `download.file` to download files to your computer. This works on all operating systems, including Linux, Mac, and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
powershell -command "iwr -outf abc.zip http://example.com/xyz.zip"
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, it would be nice if you could explain your answer for future users.