# How to download many excel files from a single url in R?

Tags: r

I have a url which contains more than a hundred xlsx files:

```
url = https://www.mrud.ir/%D9%85%D8%B3%DA%A9%D9%86/%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%AA%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%83%D9%86-%D9%88-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87-%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B2%D9%8A/%D8%A2%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D9%88-%D8%A7%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AA#196661381-------
```

I am looking to find that helps to download and save all files on disk before I can bind them together.

Answer (score 2):

Use wget command:

`wget --no-parent -r http://WEBSITE.com/DIRECTORY`

- https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

(You may need to enclose the URL in quotes)

If you need an R-specific solution, take a look at download.file util - and its built-in support for wget

- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/download.file

Also see:

- https://rdrr.io/cran/HelpersMG/man/wget.html
- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/HelpersMG/versions/4.3/topics/wget

Also see this prior question and discussion:

- [R download.file with "wget"-method and specifying extra wget options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293314/r-download-file-with-wget-method-and-specifying-extra-wget-options)